# myeclipse: can I customize templates like sysout in jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp

[Myeclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyEclipse)'s java code templates like *sysout* make coding easier, and they can also be customized. But seems it's jsp editor has no such capability.

Is it possible to create and customize some templates like *sysout* in myeclipse jsp editor, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Go to:
**MyEclipse->Preferences->MyEclipse->Files** , and
**Editors->JavaScript->Editor->Templates**.

There you can see the existing templates that work in a similar manner to the Java templates. If the context is JavaScript then they'll be available when editing JavaScript. To get the code to automatically be inserted when you enter the template name then hit Ctrl+Space, ensure the name is unique and that no other template name starts with the same characters and ensure the Auto Insert flag is also set.